# Should I run while sore?

Tags: running, muscle, pain, soreness

I would say I ran about a mile-ish in under 15 minutes, which is very slow. I'm overweight and out of shape, so I was not surprised to feel sore after it. Although, many other people are not sore, it's just me. The day after that we ran again, this time I did worse, because I still didn't heal fully. I'm not sure if I should keep pushing myself, I didn't have gym today, but I'm still in pain. Walking down the stairs is the real difficulty, I can't do a squat without it hurting. Pain is normal, but I'm not sure if I should wait to heal.

Comment: Are you being forced to exercise? I’m not sure why you are acting as if you are trapped in this situation. Besides, exercise isn’t just legs.

Comment: I'm not really trapped, I could just not run, but I am in school so technically I would have to do something, I would want suggest something else, but he's the teacher so I don't have much freedom. I am dumb, unable to just speak openly and instead I cry over nothing. Perhaps I should just get rid of that part since it doesn't add to the question, I was just really emotionally upset, not sure why. I hope I didn't annoy you at all. I want to get better, I'm not really put off by the pain, I'm annoyed at my inability to speak up.

Comment: Pain when going downstairs is one of the signs of shin splints. There are stretches that help alleviate pain from shin splints. They are also sign of over-training, you need to take it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a feel for what is normal soreness, and what is an injury developing is a difficult and important skill for a runner. If you are new to this, then build up distance slowly.

A few general notes that may help to tell the difference between soreness that's part of normal muscle (etc) development as part of exercise, and what is an injury developing:

- If the pain is extremely sharp, stop immediately
- If the pain fades as you warm up, it may be fine to continue
- If the pain is in the same place every time you run, and gets worse each time, then it's worth trying a longer gap between runs.
- If the pain is in the same place after each run, and gets worse each time, then it's worth trying a longer gap between runs.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to be ashamed of at all, your body simply isn't used to it.

> **Here is a reason you can tell your teacher.**

1. You have shin splints and let him know about the pain that's been
   getting worse when you run.
2. Have a parent write a note saying the this and stop by the your gym teachers office or you can drop it off in the morning at the principals office and ask them to give it to your teacher.

---

> **If the kids ask why you're not running say you have a "bone bruise"
>    and your doctor said not to.**

---

Below is a good article you can show your patients that talks about what can cause that. You can even print and bring it your next
        doctor visit if you want.

---

- https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/242169.php

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, almost too broad.

It very much depends on how much you exercise and afterall, only you can really judge how exhausted you feel and whether you should exercise.

It's okay to go running with during some muscle soreness, in fact it's a good thing to do as it helps to get the blood flow going. As long as it doesn't physically hurt so much that it causes you pain, then I don't see why you shouldn't be able to run.